# I am getting error 'PptxGenJS is not a constructor'

Tags: angular8, pptxgenjs

I am trying to use PptxGenJS.

I installed it by npm install pptxgenjs --save

I created very simple function, according to the examples.

When I am doing:
    import * as PptxGenJS from 'pptxgenjs';

```
const pptx = new PptxGenJS();
```

I am getting error "pptxgenjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ is not a constructor"

When I am doing:

```
let PptxGenJS = require("pptxgenjs");

let pptx = new PptxGenJS();
```

I am getting the error: "TypeError: PptxGenJS is not a constructor"

I am using 3.0.1 with Angular8 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I find out that using pptxgenjs-angular works fine.

What I done is:

```js
import * as PptxGenJS from 'pptxgenjs-angular';

const pptx = new PptxGenJS();
```

For some unknown reason, PptxGenJS failed to find the JSZip.

So I create ZIP object in my function, and send it as new parameter to

```js
const JSZip = require('jszip');

var zip = new JSZip();

pptx.save(fileName, null, null, zip);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. Import correct file, then it should work,

```
import pptxgen from "pptxgenjs";

let pres = new pptxgen();
let slide = pres.addSlide();
let textboxOpts = { x: 1, y: 1, w: '80%', h: 0.5, align: 'center', color: '131A1A', fill: 'B2E8ED', fontSize: 20 };
slide.addText("Sample text", textboxOpts);

pres.writeFile("Sample Presentation.pptx");
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure to allow synthetic default imports and esModule interoperability in your tsconfig file:

```
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
    ... 
        "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  }
```

then import in into your component like this:

```
  import PptxGenJS  from 'pptxgenjs'
```

use like this:

```
 ppt = new PptxGenJS();
```